# Git Push Not Working

Tags: github

I am working with two branches **test** and **main**.

So, being on the **main** branch, I did :

```
git merge test
```

And everything went fine. All the changes were merged.

Then to push it to the remote **main**, I did :

```
git push
```

But it seems like that did nothing, it said :

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:Company/My-App.git
b878c9d..0dc7fbe  main -> main
```

I don't think it should be showing zero above as Total if the push did go through fine.

How can I push my **main** branch ?

Comment: what you expect? git made a push and tell you that. If you do push again it will tell you "Everything up-to-date".

Comment: Right, but I wasn't expecting to see all zeros here : Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

Comment: did you check you repo via github page? just go to https://github.com/Company/My-App/commits/main, did you see your last commits ?

Comment: Yup, that shows my commits and so it means the push did go through. But why would it show all zeros in : Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) ?

Comment: It would be easier to understand with a 'modified x' ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That just means git does not write any objects. That happens when all objects are already on remote and when you merge you just move label 'main' to the latest commit. I just made a quick test to prove that:

```
    ~/workspace
    $ git clone git@github.com:korin/test_merge.git
    Cloning into 'test_merge'...
    remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
    remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
    Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.

    ~/workspace
    $ cd test_merge
    ~/workspace/test_merge

    $ git co -b test
    Switched to a new branch 'test'

    ~/workspace/test_merge
    $ echo 'a' > a

    ~/workspace/test_merge
    $ git add .

    ~/workspace/test_merge
    $ git ci -m 'a'
    [test 9953350] a
     1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
     create mode 100644 a

    ~/workspace/test_merge
    $ git push --set-upstream origin test
    Counting objects: 4, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 273 bytes, done.
    Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
    To git@github.com:korin/test_merge.git
     * [new branch]      test -> test
    Branch test set up to track remote branch test from origin.

    ~/workspace/test_merge
    $ g co master
    Switched to branch 'master'

    ~/workspace/test_merge
    $ g merge test
    Updating f5e0184..9953350
    Fast-forward
     a |    1 +
     1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
     create mode 100644 a

    ~/workspace/test_merge
    $ g push
    Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
    To git@github.com:korin/test_merge.git
         f5e0184..9953350  master -> master
```

Comment: g stands for git, it just an alias